# What does return -1 here mean?

Tags: python, return

When looping up answers to some job interview questions, I got this bit of code and am confused as to what `return -1` is doing, and I guess how this code is actually accomplishing the task.

```py
#First Non-Repeating Integer in an Array
def firstNonRepeating(arr, n): 
  
    for i in range(n): 
        j = 0
        while(j < n): 
            if (i != j and arr[i] == arr[j]): 
                break
            j += 1
        if (j == n): 
            return arr[i] 
      
    return -1
      
# Driver code 
arr = [ 9, 4, 9, 6, 7, 4 ] 
n = len(arr) 
print(firstNonRepeating(arr, n))
```

Comment: It would mean that all the items in the array appears more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's being used as a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) for when all the integers repeat, for example:

```
>>> a = [9, 4, 9, 4]
>>> firstNonRepeating(a, len(a))
-1
```

However, that's a **terrible** choice of sentinel value, because it's also a perfectly legal value:

```
>>> arr = [-1]
>>> print(firstNonRepeating(arr, len(arr)))
-1
```

It would be better to raise an exception, like:

```
raise ValueError('no non-repeating integer found')
```

Maybe the writer was thinking of **unsigned** integers, which don't exist in Python (at least not as a native type). There are a bunch of other oddities that make me think it was written by someone more familiar with say, C, than Python (namely, passing in the length of an array, looping over numbers with `while` instead of `for ... range`, referring to a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)/[sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) as an array, and parentheses around the `if` tests).

Comment: why not just retrun the values that is the firstnonrepeating intg?

Comment: @0004 What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The `return -1` is for when every element in the array is repeating

Ex:

```
Input - 1, 1, 1
Output - -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally when there is no solution present for the given input, then for indication purpose -1 is returned as the answer.

Here function *firstNonRepeating* will return -1 when all the integers present at least twice in the array.